# How to automate NirSoft MultiMonitorTool using Windows task scheduler?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I'm using the freeware software [MultiMonitorTool](https://nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) to automate the configuration of displays on a Windows 11 computer.

I got two Batch scripts that "do" (disable the physical display) and "undo" (enable the physical display) using `MultiMonitorTool.exe`. The file contents do not matter for this question. Everything works as expected, if I'm logged into the Windows command and execute the scripts.

I'm currently trying to automate the "undo" batch script execution using the [Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) of Windows.

The main issue is that the `MultiMonitorTool.exe` calls in the batch scripts only have an effect if the task option "Run only when user is logged on" is activated. I tested this by executing the task manually from the Task Scheduler GUI.

I tried different things, e.g. running the batch script using the `SYSTEM` account and/or with the task option "Run with highest privileges" activated. All this doesn't help, the batch script does have an effect only if the task option "Run only when user is logged on" is activated.

The problem that follows the mentioned main issue is that I'm unable to execute the "Run only when user is logged on" task with the triggers "Boot" and the following two "Events":

- "Shutdown": `System` | `User32` | `1074`
- "Wake Up": `System` | `Power-Troubleshooter` | `1`

While "Wake Up" shouldn't work (the user is not logged in then), I assumed that "Shutdown" should work, but maybe this is triggered after logout.

I tried to workaround this limitation by using different triggers, e.g. "Logon", "On Workstation unlock" and "On Workstation lock". Some of these have an effect, but the issue with this approach is that these triggers are "too late", i.e. I've to interact with the computer dealing with a disabled display (if "do" has been called).

Do you have any suggestions how I can improve the task settings to ensure that the `MultiMonitorTool.exe` calls in the batch script are successfully executed?

I'm already thinking about workarounds, such as trigger a "Run only when user is logged on" task by using a keyboard combination, but I don't know if that is possible (and the best solution). Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you have the files stored? If you for example store it within your user profile folder, for example My Documents, then only your user has rights, and other users will fail. If this is the case, create a dedicated folder somewhere on your harddisk with the scripts, and see if it now works if you specify system or your own user, but with the option whether or not the user is logged in.

Comment: The display settings can **only** be changed by the currently logged on user, in that logged in session, due to how windows isolates sessions. It depends what you need this for, but you can probably just trigger your scheduled task "At log on" and/or "On workstation unlock" to get it to run properly

Comment: A process that's disassociated from the running user session cannot affect the display in any way. It's a security measure.

Comment: If you need display changes *before* logon (like to change where the logon itself shows), there are some awkward ways like disabling other monitor devices via `Disable-PnpDevice` that should work without a logon session, but are not needed in most cases.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Yes, I already assumed that the dependency to a user session is a feature (and not a bug) in my OP. I also mentioned that I tried "Logon" and "On Workstation unlock". These two do work and do succesfully execute the script, but both triggers are called "too late". Note that the "do" script disables the primary display and the "undo" script enables it. Imagine the host crashes after "undo". Now I'm left with no display when restarting the host. I could login "blind" (which would then trigger the "undo" script), but this is not a solution, but a hack.

Comment: @LPChip The script files are stored in `C:\foo`. As others stated I don't think this is a file permission issue, but an operating system feature that prevents other users to mess with the display settings.

Comment: Can you use `WIN`+`P,P`, then `[Enter]` to re-enable the primary display? That works from the lock screen even if you can't see it, but it depends on how you're disabling the screen in the first place.

Comment: If not, you can probably re-enable it with powershell. Find the monitor's ID with `Get-PnpDevice -Class MONITOR -Status OK | Select InstanceID`, then you can run `Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId 'DISPLAY\ABC1234\SOMEID' -Confirm:$false` in a task at startup - assuming that's what your tool is doing

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I've already tried `WIN` + `P`, but it didn't seem to work at all on the login screen on my Windows 11 host. I'll retry. Regarding the PowerShell command: That should work without a user logged in? I'll try that too. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @FlorianWolters I haven't tested. A good troubleshooting step would be to dump the list to a file after disabling the display, like `Get-PnpDevice -Class MONITOR | Export-Csv "C:\temp\monitors.csv"` and see what status the "correct" monitor is in before and after (and also verify the script ran etc)